# How do I access current IdentityUser properties if a User is logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I created this app using the default for blazorwasm template with individual Auth. Below is some of my csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>


<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.0-preview3.20168.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>


<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I am trying to retrieve properties from my ApplicationUser which derives from IdentityUser, when a User is logged in of course. I currently am looking at 3 classes(UserManager, SignInManager, and ApplicationUser). Also I extended the ApplicationUser with a property that I want to retrieve. This property is for querying the database for only the records with this property value. In other words, the values from the database table AspNetUsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a service class to handle this in my application. From my controller I setup `ApplicationUser user` and then called into the service I created `user = await this._userServices.GetUserInformation(User)` (the capitalized User is the logged-in user)

In the user service class, this is what I have:

```
public class UserServices : IUserServices
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserServices(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserInformation(ClaimsPrincipal userClaim)
    {
        var userId = userClaim?.FindFirst("UserId")?.Value; // returns null if no user logged in
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        return user;
    }
}
```

After you call this, you can do a null check on your user.

The user information that you get from here, which is what's in your AspNetUsers table, will have the field you need.

Hope this helps.